# How to get variable value outside for loop and if statement

Tags: ionic-framework

there is any way to get the variable value outside the for and if statement ?

this is a example of what i want:

```
maxNumber:any = 0;

 this.http.get("http://www.yyyyyyy.ma/yyyyyy.php").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data =>{
  this.Numbres = data

      for(let N of this.Numbres){
          if(N.Max != 0){
              maxNumber = n.Max;
          }
      }
});

 console.log("max nombre is :" this.maxNumber);
```

max nombre is : 6

Comment: actually it should work as you mentioned, do you tried it?

Comment: if you use a outside variable within an function it will bound to the function´s static lexical scope. So if you dont shadow it with your function´s arguments or something else you should be able to read and also write it´s value

Comment: yes it works, my bad